# Spring Boot Test returns 401 but applicaiton returns 403 when calling it. Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint is not invoked for tests but is for real app

Tags: spring, testing, spring-security

POST http://localhost:8080/login on real running app gets me 403.
But the followin test will get me 401

```
@Test
fun `test`() {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")).andExpect(status().isForbidden)
    //will fail - returns 401 instead of 403
}
```

While running the app and calling POST http://localhost:8080/login DEUBG logs will say:

```
2023-06-24T17:32:42.407+02:00 DEBUG 16560 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Sending 401 Unauthorized error
2023-06-24T17:32:42.411+02:00 DEBUG 16560 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-06-24T17:32:42.412+02:00 DEBUG 16560 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-06-24T17:32:42.413+02:00 DEBUG 16560 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

I would like tests to behave exactly like the real app but they seem to lack this Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint class being invoked why is that and how to fix it?

I tried @ContextConfiguration(classes = [SecurityConfig::class]) but it wont load compalaing that it cant find beans.
I tried

```
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity()) 
            .build()
```

but it didnt change anything

I would like tests to behave exactly like the real app but they seem to lack this Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint class being invoked why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the spring boot documentation on how spring boot handles errors?

Comment: Can you post your security config and the exact error you receive when failing to load beans please ? Also in your first paragraph you say running the real app returns a 403 but your DEBUG logs example says 401. What if the difference between these two ? Are your running the same app and enabling logs at DEBUG level or are your running the app in debug mode (if so, does anything change in how you build or start your application? )